# Create branch inherited from master

Tags: git

If I create a branch in the terminal

```
git checkout -b 'test_branch2'
```

this branch will be inherited from the branch on which I was before that (in  my case, `test_branch1`).

I need to create a branch inherited from `master` in the terminal, how do I do that?

Comment: checkout the desired branch to inherit from (`git checkout master`), then create the new branch (`git checkout -b newbranch`)

Comment: how to do it? say in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch in Git is not inherently related to any other branch.

A branch is only a "pointer" or "bookmark" to a commit and therefore refers to that commit and all of its ancestors.

The command

```
git checkout -b 'test_branch2'
```

creates a new branch which points to the commit that is currently "active" (the one which the special `HEAD` reference points to).

The command accepts as additional argument the name of, or reference to, a particular commit. Such a reference can for example be another branch.

So in order to create a new branch that points to the same commit as the branch `master` currently does, you can use

```
git checkout -b test_branch2 master
```

(the quotes aren't required in this case, by the way)

Note again, this doesn't make `test_branch2` in any way related to `master`, they only happen to point to the same commit *now*, but that could change in the future.